# Beginner question: Put script in start up?

Tags: scripts

I'd like to put this basic script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch" touch off
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser" touch off
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad" touch off
```

In the start-up applications.

I'm a beginner, so I'm not sure what to do now - currently I just double-click on the script via PCManFM and hit "Execute".

Comment: This question is uplicate: [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your script somewhere with executable permissions:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

In unity dash, search for startup applications in command options, select your script to enable it to be run on every startup

Comment: @begtognen Glad it helped...  P.S. In accordance with the forum rules, please upvote an answer to 'like' it, and select an answer by using the check mark icon next to the answer, to help others identify the solution which worked for you. This system ensures focus to be on the right answers among the lot!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it in Ubuntu is probably just to use the Startup Applications tool. Put your script in wherever it needs to be, then specify the full path to it (For example, /home/begtognen/script.sh).

Hopefully that will run that script on startup. I use this to start my Thunderbird whenever I login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~/.xprofile` to add commands executed after X login.